# How to get actual type in Java?

Tags: java

Hi I'm new to Java so this question might be ridiculous though, I wonder how to get actual type in Java.

I mean, let's say there's a code block as belows:

```java
List<String> foo_list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> foo_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then `foo_list.getClass()` and `foo_arrayList.getClass()` both would return "java.util.ArrayList" right?

but if I try to pass foo_list into a function that expects `ArrayList<String>` as a argument, it causes compile time error like follows:

```
java: method X in class Y cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
  found: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
  reason: actual argument java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> by method invocation conversion
```

so even though that `foo_list.getClass()` returns "java.util.ArrayList", I guess(from the error log) its actual type is "java.util.List<java.lang.String>".. (I might guess wrong)

**how can I get the "java.util.List<java.lang.String>" with `foo_list`?**

thanks.

Comment: Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there's no such thing as  `java.util.List<java.lang.String>` at runtime.

Comment: @jsheeran oh wow "type erasure" I didn't know that! thanks for the keyword

Comment: @jsheeran but on second thought, at least, can't I get "java.util.List" instead of "java.util.ArrayList"? I think this might not relate to generic.

Comment: `java.util.List` is an interface which `java.util.ArrayList` implements. At best you can get all the interface that are implemented by `java.util.ArrayList` with a call to `foo_list.getClass().getInterfaces()`. This however returns all interfaces and not just one, leaving you to find the correct one again

Comment: That is why your compiler has types. It expects an ArrayList and not all `List`s are `ArrayList`. You can cast if you want to though. Since you know it is an array list "(ArrayList<String>)foo_list"

Comment: @jsheeran Or without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing compile-time type with runtime type. At compile time, your `foo_list` is indeed a `List<String>` because that's how you declared it. The only way to check its compile-time type is to look at your code. Check the place where you declare the variable, and you'll see what its type is.

At runtime, your `foo_list` is an `ArrayList`. (Not an `ArrayList<String>` because the parameter `<String>` is lost due to type erasure. By the way, type erasure happens only at runtime. There is no type erasure at compile time.)

Comment: baam... compile-time type and runtime type, with them, all this myth is solved. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here is to have the interface as a parameter to the method, not the implementation. In your particular case, if the method takes List instead of ArrayList, everything will work. Not only that, you will be able to shove other List interface implementations into this method as well - which is cool.

Comment: yes that function was created on purpose, and from the comment now I know that this is impossible in Java due to "type erasure", I think I could close this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic casting. You don't need to even use Generics.

```
List<String> foo_list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> foo_list2 = (ArrayList<String>)foo_list;
```

Now you can call your method with `foo_list2`.

You could do the same thing with an Object.

```
Object a = "a string";
String s = (String)a;
```

A method `public void check(String i)` would accept `s` but there would be a compile time error if you tried to call `check(a)`.